# Can i use _source field inside aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with some many fields, i want to find the count of documents that are inserted after certain hour which can be done by using range query but among all documents fields i want the only Timestamp field should be displayed .

I used the following query

```
 {
      "_source": [
        "fields.Timestamp"
      ],
      "aggs": {
        "last_5_mins": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "fields.Timestamp": {
                "gt": "2017-02-10T10:07:04.4367673Z"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

When i saw the output i didnt get the Timestamp for the matched documents rather i got for the documents that are not matched with my query.

MY output:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "matrix",
        "_type": "neo",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {

        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "matrix",
        "_type": "neo",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "fields": {
            "Timestamp": "2017-02-10T10:07:04.4367673Z"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "matrix",
        "_type": "neo",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "fields": {
            "Timestamp": "2017-02-10T10:07:04.4836472Z"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "matrix",
        "_type": "neo",
        "_id": "6",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {

        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "matrix",
        "_type": "neo",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "fields": {
            "Timestamp": "2017-02-10T10:07:04.4367673Z"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "matrix",
        "_type": "neo",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "fields": {
            "Timestamp": "2017-02-10T10:07:12.1147415Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "last_5_mins": {
      "doc_count": 2
    }
  }
}
```

How can i get the timestamp for the matched documents?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use an aggregation for that, simply move your `range` query in the query section and you're good:

```
{
   "_source": [
      "fields.Timestamp"
   ],
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": {
            "range": {
               "fields.Timestamp": {
                  "gt": "2017-02-10T10:07:04.4367673Z"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..May i know why you didnt used filter for this? Because without filter it will be a costly search for searching `fields.Timestamp`. And also i want the count of documents too.

Comment: There, using a filter now. Just know that not using filters doesn't equate to "costly", there are many other factors coming into play. The count of documents is the `hits.total` value in the response.

Comment: Thanks ..val it helped..May i know what are factors that you are taking about?

Comment: It depends on how fields are mapped, what kind of queries you're sending, how many docs you have, hardware specs, etc